# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent relationship return Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

this is may route code

```
Route::get('/dashboard',['middleware' => 'auth', function () {

    $links = App\Website_links::where('website_id',1)->get();
    return view('user.dashboard',['links_data'=>$links]);

}]);
```

and website_link model code is

```
class Website_links extends Model
{
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $table = 'website_links';

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Website','website_id')
                    ->select('project_name','project_status');
    }
 }
```

and view code

```
@foreach($links_data as $links)
         <tr>
         <td><a href="">{{$links['page_url']}}</a></td>
         <td>{{$links['project']}}</td>// here i want to display project_name from website table
         </tr>
    @endforeach
```

databse schema:

```
  website : id,project_name,project_status
  website_links: id, page_url, website_id   //here website_id is forign key.
```

now its shows page_url correctly but

```
{{$links['project']}} display {"project_name":"Project1","id":45}
```

and i want to show project_name value like project1 instead of whole array

```
  {"project_name":"Project1","id":45}
```

Comment: what do you get on var_dump($links) in you route ??

Comment: The problem is that you return an **object** from your route, and are trying to access it like an *array*. Instead of `$links['page_url']` try `$links->page_url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$links['project'] to $link->project->project_name

@foreach($links_data as $links) 
     <tr>
         <td>
             <a href="">{{$links['page_url']}}</a>
         </td> 
        <td>
             {{$links->project->project_name}}
        </td>// here i want to display project_name from website table
     </tr> 
@endforeach
```

And change your query to the following to prevent the N+1 query problem

```
$links = App\Website_links::with('project')->where('website_id',1)->get();
```

Comment: ErrorException in 1a1a8e95628b2f75f2f18eca4a89360de61acef6.php line 92:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Sorry am using my phone so finding it difficult to type all at a go. I have updated my answer.

Comment: no problem..but i am getting same problem trying to get property of non-object in view.. sorry em new in laravel.

Comment: Change $link['page_url] to $links->page_url